# How to count image of gallery in wordpress gallery shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display total of item in wordpress gallery each post.
I code this, But it not work. The post display wrong number of item in gallery.

```
$args = array(
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
);

$pattern = get_shortcode_regex();
preg_match('/'.$pattern.'/s', $post->post_content, $matches);
if (is_array($matches) && $matches[2] == 'gallery') {
    // do something
    preg_match('/\[ gallery ids=\"(.*?)\"]/',$matches[0],$ids);

    if (is_array($ids) && $ids[1] ) {
        $photos = explode(',',$ids[1]);
    } else {
        $photos = get_children( $args );
    }
    $total_images = count($photos);
}
```

Comment: in post_type 'attachment' can more be than expected, eg pictures that have been uploaded to that post directly or PDF's,tried to parse `$photos` that it holds pictures of your gallery?

Comment: I pass post_mime_type as 'image'. I think that will filter by attachment type image.